# file upload how to get the http.Dir path

Tags: go

The directory of my file system is the following.

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(uploadPath))
```

And I want to upload the file under this folder.

```
func upload(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {

    r.ParseMultipartForm(maxUploadSize)

    _, file, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        return web.NewRequestError(err, http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    if file.Size > maxUploadSize {
        return web.NewRequestError(err, http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    fileName := filepath.Base(file.Filename)
    filePath := filepath.Join(http.Dir(uploadPath), fileName) // I want to get dir path.
    if err := saveUploadedFile(file, filePath); err != nil {
        return web.NewRequestError(err, http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    return web.Respond(ctx, w, fileName, http.StatusOK)
}

func saveUploadedFile(file *multipart.FileHeader, dst string) error {
    src, err := file.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer src.Close()

    out, err := os.Create(dst)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer out.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(out, src)
    return err
}
```

But the `http.Dir(uploadPath)` can not be join with `fileName`, how should I fix it?

My project tree.

```
my-api
 |- uploadPath
 |- handler
     |- my handler file
 |- test
     |- my test file
 |- main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I config my root path in my dockerfile, there are two ways to fix with it.

```
// 1. hardcode the '/rootPath' same as the dockerfile configure.
filePath := filepath.Join("/rootPath", uploadPath, fileName)

// 2. Dynamically get the current root path.
ex, err := os.Executable()
if err != nil {
    ...
}
rootPath := filepath.Dir(ex)
filePath := filepath.Join(rootPath, uploadPath, fileName)
```

Thanks to Marc for the tip of it.

Answer (score 2):

`http.Dir(uploadPath)` is an explicit type conversion from `string` to [http.Dir](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Dir) which is just a string with a `Open` method.

That means no processing is done on the string and you can do the `filepath.Join` directly on the original string:

```
filePath := filepath.Join(uploadPath, fileName)
```

Note: the reason you use `http.Dir` to convert the argument to `http.FileServer` is for the `Dir.Open` method which implements the [http.Filesystem](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileSystem) interface.

Comment: The http.Dir(uploadPath)  return the ./my-api/uploadPath/, but the uploadPath return the ./my-api/handlers/uploadPath/, is it means they are not the same?

Comment: It doesn't change the string, it's just a type conversion: https://play.golang.org/p/ghOip07R0d8. You or some middleware must be modifying it somewhere but it's not in the code you have shown.

Comment: How to get the absolute path under my-api to force the same with each other?

Comment: It's not about absolute path, something in your code is inserting `handlers` but you're not showing the relevant portions.

Comment: I tried the `"uploadPath"` and `"../uploadPath"`, they are all return `no such file or directory`. But in the test file I using `"../uploadPath"` it can be passed. I update the directory of my project.

Comment: You need to build your path once and use the same value everywhere. Don't use the working directory, that could be anything. Instead, her the path from a flag, environnement variable, or configuration file.